# SQL - Remove all duplicates from earlier dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this example data in my database:

```
Order number | Date       | Item
23           | 2017-05-23 | Apple
23           | 2017-05-23 | Banana
24           | 2017-05-24 | Apple
23           | 2018-03-21 | Apple
23           | 2018-03-21 | Banana
```

This might seem like a weird SQL - query, but I want to get all of the order numbers from each day with their containing date and item, BUT if the order number has been registered on several dates, I only want the "oldest" instance.

The answer should in this case be:

```
Order number | Date       | Item
23           | 2017-05-23 | Apple
23           | 2017-05-23 | Banana
24           | 2017-05-24 | Apple
```

Thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more standard way of writing this query, besides what Gordon gave, would be to just join to a subquery which finds the latest record for each order/item group:

```
SELECT o1.*
FROM orders o1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT o_num, item, MIN(Date) AS min_date
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY o_num, item
) o2
    ON o1.o_num = o2.o_num AND o1.item = o2.item AND o1.Date = o2.min_date;
```

In MySQL 8+, which supports basic analytic functions, we could write this query more succinctly as:

```
SELECT o_num, Date, item
FROM
(
    SELECT o_num, Date, item,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o_num, item ORDER BY Date) rn
    FROM orders
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select o.*
from orders o
where (o.order, o.date) in (select o2.order, min(o2.date) from orders o2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and simpliest way to do it is:

```
Select [order number], Min([Date]) as [Oldest Date], [Item]
From [your table]
Group by [order number], [Item]
```

Comment: This essentially repeats a previous answer, but without the scalability afforded by that answer.

Comment: i see, can you please point to me who posted it so i can check it ? i can't figure wich one it is, thank you

Comment: See Tim's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use *correlated* `subquery` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where date = (select max(t1.date) from table t1 where t1.orderno = t.orderno);
```

Perhaps you also need item in `where` clause.